# Consulta Erronea

Tags: c#

oigan alguien me puede decir cual es mi error:

```
public DataTable Programas(int Programa, String LoteI, String LoteF)
    {
        DataTable dt = null;

        String query = "SELECT DL.Programa, IL.Modelo, IL.Color, IL.Cliente, IL.Linea, DL.Cantidad, DL.Lote, DL.T150, DL.T155, DL.T160, DL.T165, DL.T170, DL.T175, DL.T180, DL.T185, DL.T190, DL.T195, DL.T200, DL.T205, DL.T210, DL.T215," +
                       "DL.T220, DL.T225, DL.T230, DL.T235, DL.T240, DL.T245, DL.T250, DL.T255, DL.T260, DL.T265, DL.T270, DL.T275, DL.T280, DL.T285, DL.T290, DL.T295, DL.T300  " +
                       "FROM InfoLote AS IL INNER JOIN DetalleLote AS DL ON IL.Programa = DL.Programa WHERE (DL.Programa = '" + Programa + "') AND (DL.Lote BETWEEN '"+ LoteI +"' AND '"+ LoteF +"')";
        dt = daccess.select(query);
        return dt;
    }
```

llevo ya bastante, he cambiado ya muchas veces la instruccion sql, pero sigue sin dar, se supone que me debería de arrojar todos los datos correspondientes cuando pongo el numero de programa, pero solo me aparece este resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya lo compare con otros códigos que tengo y al parecer no hay nada mal.

Comment: Deberias agregar la estructura de las tablas.

Comment: estas seguro que el INNER JOIN no esta haciendo que no obtengas registros, o sea siempre hay datos en ambas tablas que se relacionan, porque sino deberias usar un LEFT JOIN

Comment: Si no vemos tus datos y las condiciones, no vamos a poder decirte porque esto no funciona.

Comment: Me la juego a que tu problema esta en el `WHERE`. Probaste sacarlo para saber si el resto de la consulta esta bien? Seria un buen comienzo para descartar. Aparte, los valor del `WHERE` son todos `string`? estas comparando con cadenas literales. Es decir, que si te equivocas en una letra, directamente no se cumple la condición.

Comment: si quito esta instrucción: AND (DL.Lote BETWEEN '"+ LoteI +"' AND '"+ LoteF +"') , si me muestra los datos sin ningún problema, el problema es que los datos de LoteI y LoteF los dejo vacios y es cuando no me muestra nada, pero ya he hecho este tipo de consultas y funcionan sin ningún problema, en el cual solo meto un parametro y me muestra los datos, y aqui no entiendo porque no

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tienes que usaer parametros en el codigo no es bueno concatenar en un string los valores

```
DataTabla dt = new DataTable(); 
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring")) 
{ 

    string query = @"SELECT DL.Programa, IL.Modelo, IL.Color, IL.Cliente, IL.Linea, DL.Cantidad, DL.Lote, DL.T150, DL.T155, DL.T160, DL.T165, DL.T170, DL.T175, DL.T180, DL.T185, DL.T190, DL.T195, DL.T200, DL.T205, DL.T210, DL.T215,
                   DL.T220, DL.T225, DL.T230, DL.T235, DL.T240, DL.T245, DL.T250, DL.T255, DL.T260, DL.T265, DL.T270, DL.T275, DL.T280, DL.T285, DL.T290, DL.T295, DL.T300 
                   FROM InfoLote AS IL INNER JOIN DetalleLote AS DL ON IL.Programa = DL.Programa 
                   WHERE (DL.Programa = @Programa) AND (DL.Lote BETWEEN @LoteI AND @LoteF)";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Programa", Programa);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoteI", LoteI);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoteF", LoteF);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); 
    da.Fill(dt); 
}
```

adapta `daccess.select()` para poder pasarle una lista de SqlParameter o sino descartalo porque asi como esta, no es correcto

Por otro lado prueba ir variando el query para ver como cambia su respuesta y determinar que hace que no devuelva registros, podrias quitar el inner join, podrias quitar los parametros, despues agregar solo uno y despues el otro, ve cambiando para ver como responde

Si necesitas que el filtro sea condicional puedes aplicar algo como esto

```
DataTabla dt = new DataTable(); 
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring")) 
{ 

    string query = @"SELECT DL.Programa, IL.Modelo, IL.Color, IL.Cliente, IL.Linea, DL.Cantidad, DL.Lote, DL.T150, DL.T155, DL.T160, DL.T165, DL.T170, DL.T175, DL.T180, DL.T185, DL.T190, DL.T195, DL.T200, DL.T205, DL.T210, DL.T215,
                   DL.T220, DL.T225, DL.T230, DL.T235, DL.T240, DL.T245, DL.T250, DL.T255, DL.T260, DL.T265, DL.T270, DL.T275, DL.T280, DL.T285, DL.T290, DL.T295, DL.T300 
                   FROM InfoLote AS IL INNER JOIN DetalleLote AS DL ON IL.Programa = DL.Programa 
                   WHERE (DL.Programa = @Programa) 
                   AND ((@LoteI IS NULL) OR (DL.Lote BETWEEN @LoteI AND @LoteF))";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Programa", Programa);

    if(opcional) //aqui condicion si aplica o no ese filtro
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoteI", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoteF", DBNull.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoteI", LoteI);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoteF", LoteF);
    }

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); 
    da.Fill(dt); 
}
```

como veras en el WHERE puede preguntar si el parametro es null y anular esa condicion, alli pregunte solo por un parametro, pero aplica en ambos

Comment: si le quito la instrucción de between, si me muestra los datos, pero si le dejo la instrucción de BETWEEN ya no me manda los datos, porque esos los dejo vacios, pero ya he hecho esto antes y si me funciona sin ningun problema, aqui no entiendo porque no me muestra los datos

Comment: como que los dejas vacios ? eso que significa, en la query como la estas armando todos los parametros son obligatorios

Comment: me pregunto cuando votan negativo puedes explicar porque? acaso consideran que una pesima practica de no usar parametros es bien vista

Comment: bueno es que no siempre se va a buscar un programa por el numero de lote, la mayoría de las veces solo es poner el puro programa, pero ya lo resolví poniendo un if, acerca de porque votan negativo, quien sabe, tendrán sus motivos

Comment: pero puede poner filtros condicionales si pasas como parametro un null, o mejor dicho un DBNull.Value, espera que edito el ejemplo